# how can i convert WMS link to WMTS link in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have geoserver WMS link. How can I convert to WMTS link?

WMS:
http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/saba/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=saba%3Ageotools_coverage&bbox=-2.0037508342789244E7%2C-2.0037508343038823E7%2C2.0037508342789244E7%2C2.0037508343038812E7&width=767&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A3857&styles=&format=application/openlayers

User: demo
Pass: 123

Answer (score 0):

You use the information in the [WMTS getcapabilities document](http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?services=WMTS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities), so anyone of the templates in:

```
      <ResourceURL format="image/png" resourceType="tile" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}?format=image/png"/>
      <ResourceURL format="image/jpeg" resourceType="tile" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}?format=image/jpeg"/>
      <ResourceURL format="text/plain" resourceType="FeatureInfo" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}/{J}/{I}?format=text/plain"/>
      <ResourceURL format="application/vnd.ogc.gml" resourceType="FeatureInfo" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}/{J}/{I}?format=application/vnd.ogc.gml"/>
      <ResourceURL format="text/xml" resourceType="FeatureInfo" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}/{J}/{I}?format=text/xml"/>
      <ResourceURL format="application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1" resourceType="FeatureInfo" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}/{J}/{I}?format=application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1"/>
      <ResourceURL format="text/xml" resourceType="FeatureInfo" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}/{J}/{I}?format=text/xml"/>
      <ResourceURL format="text/html" resourceType="FeatureInfo" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}/{J}/{I}?format=text/html"/>
      <ResourceURL format="application/json" resourceType="FeatureInfo" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}/{J}/{I}?format=application/json"/>
      <ResourceURL format="application/json" resourceType="TileJSON" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/tilejson/png?format=application/json"/>
      <ResourceURL format="application/json" resourceType="TileJSON" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/saba:geotools_coverage/{style}/tilejson/jpeg?format=application/json"/><ResourceURL resourceType="layerStyles" format="text/json" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/reststyles/layers/saba:geotools_coverage/styles/?f=text%2Fjson"/><ResourceURL resourceType="defaultStyle" format="application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml" template="http://103.215.221.11:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/reststyles/layers/saba:geotools_coverage/styles/raster?f=application%2Fvnd.ogc.sld%2Bxml"/>
```